# The bluest conifer of all time

Tags: plant-recommendations, conifers

I am creating a group of blue conifers in a small corner of my garden.

A woman from a nursery I occasionaly order plants from claims that there is no bluer conifer than Picea pungens 'Edith'.

Is she right?

*(Photoshop-edited photos and artificially created foliage color do not count, like that blue japanese maple from a recent question)*

[image]

Comment: Picea pungens 'Edith', also known as Colorado Blue Spruce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say - human colour perception varies between individuals,so what you might think is the bluest one, someone else won't.Your best option is to go and look at them in real life, in good daylight, and pick  the one that looks bluest to you. I've used Picea pungens 'hoopsii',or 'Koster', but both 'Edith' and 'Superblue' have a more silvery bluish look in my view.

The most blue one to me is not a Picea at all, it's Chamaecyparis pisifera 'boulevard', but it's a darker blue than the others mentioned. Many turn a darker or lighter tone in winter, but essentially, it's down to personal perception and preference.